# hasRow returns false on populated database - SQLite4Java

Tags: java, database, sqlite, netbeans

I am trying to retrieve all the rows that are in my database with the following code:

[image: Code]

I have created a class that holds two objects, simply for the purpose of testing whether the code works or not (It will be expanded for the chance of differing amounts of columns at a later date) .

When execution reaches the if statement, it evaluates to false and breaks out of the loop even though this tool shows there is inface data inside of it:

[image: Database]

The sample on the authors website seems to be similar and searches for better examples have returned nothing of use.

Where am I going wrong, is it my initial configuration of the SQL statement or is it the way I am handling the query returned?

Thanks.

Comment: Nope, code formatting wouldn't work properly on here so I gave up and just submitted it as a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SQLiteStatement.hasRow()` returns true if there's data to be read with the `columnXYZ` methods. This will only happen after you've called `SQLiteStatement.step()` at least once.

The call to hasRow in your example isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

What does `db.open(false)` return? Perhaps you are creating an empty database rather than opening the one you think.

Perhaps you meant `user.home`?